# React native alt dispatcher this.dispatch is not a function Babel 6

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs

I upgraded my project from RN 0.15.0 to 0.16.0 this morning and with that came many errors due to passing to Babel 6.
There is one that I don't figure out (I guess its something missing in my .babelrc file)

This code worked fine before upgrading :

```
'use strict';

import alt from '../alt';
import MeStore from '../stores/Me';

export class MeActions {
 showedCurrentPosition(showed) {
    this.dispatch(showed);
  }
}

export default alt.createActions(MeActions);
```

Here is my Alt.js file using the plugin alt :

```
'use strict';

import Alt from 'alt';
export default new Alt();
```

Now, I get when running my code "this.dispatch is not a function" when calling `MeActions.showedCurrentPosition(true);`

[image: Error thrown when running app]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably ended up upgrading Alt as well. A recent release got rid of dispatch in favor of simple returns. Check out the documentation on Actions http://alt.js.org/docs/createActions/

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, how are we supposed to dispatch before an async operation starts if we have to return from the action to dispatch it?

I used to dispatch at the start of the action then run the async stuff and dispatch in either the success or failure handler to update the state again.

Comment: I'm doing as you're saying. Dispatching at the start (loading state = true usually) then either success of failure handler turning the loading state in false. I'd be interested if you have another way of doing it.